# Changing the border of rectangle in jPanel

Tags: java, swing

I ama drawing a rectangle in a panel and i added a + button to increase my shape's size.how can i do it?

Comment: while i click button it should be bigger and bigger.Now i drawed rectangle in a panel but i think i should add some methods

Answer (score 3):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics.

Now, in your class that does the custom painting you need to keep two variables:

rectangleWidth
rectangleHeight

You will also need to add a method to the class like "increaseRectangleSize()". Then when you click your button you invoke that method. That method will increase the values of those two variables and then invoke repaint() on itself.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem since your description of the problem is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to draw a bigger rectangle.  In the paintComponent method that you are drawing a the rectangle increase the size.  If you are trying to make the JPanel bigger, I would highly suggest you looking using Layout Managers and possibly set the PreferredSize() of the panel.

Comment: i am trying to draw bigger rectangle but i want to make it bigger when i click the button

Comment: Add an event listener to the button that changes a variable that is used while painting.